# Ruby/Mechanize: Not getting all the cookies after logging into a page

Tags: python, ruby, cookies, mechanize

When I log into a page in my browser, I get 3 cookies: `tips`, `ipb_member_id` and `ip_pass_hash`. I need those last two to access some pages I can only see when logged in. When I log in via the browser it works fine, but under mechanize I only get the tips cookie.

Are there any flags I have to set up for this to work, or is there any module I might need? I can't link to the page here. Though I do know Python's Mechanize + cookielib stores the cookies correctly, since I already have a working version for it.

Comment: which version of mechanize? Try 1.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the same issue (I want to get all cookies loaded on a page).
I think it's impossible with mechanize. One reason is that it doesn't support javascript, so anything a little bit complex (such as a img loaded on a js event, which set a new cookie) will not work.
I am considering other options as webkit :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730906/automating-chrome

if you find a good way to gather all the cookies, let me know :)