# using chrome programmatically

Tags: google-chrome, automation, external

I know it's not exactly the use for a browser one could expect, but it would be useful it there was a way to explore the DOM of a page (read/set values) and send commands (clicks, for example) with automation, not manually.
It could be with C, C#, even VBScript, for what I care, or DDE (but this seems to be a no), or using a third party extension... Anything could do.
The fact is that this way could be difficult, but precise. I could use AutoIt, for example, but it would blindly execute the script without really having the possibility of managing problems.
The browser has to be chrome. I don't have much hope, but I can still ask...

The obvious answer would be "make your own extension", but I'm trying to avoid that.

UPDATE
The "headless browser" thing seems nice, but in effect I need to use the interface by hand before leaving it to the automation, it should remain visible.
...Essentially because I need to activate an app, and I do it by hand, but I'm searching if there's another way.
EDIT
Yeah, it seems they are 'explorable' by url, so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=chrome+headless+browser

Comment: I'd also suggest looking at http://stackoverflow.com/a/20712857/227494 and adding "browser automation," "UI automation," and/or "automated testing" to your searches. There are great tools out there, and as Jim says they're all going to need a reasonable bit of learning and work to get exactly what you want - no one tool will fit everyone's systems and needs, because of course everyone's systems and needs are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The favorite seems to be Watir, then Selenium, then Watin.
Possibly I may need some other tool, but this part shoul be covered.
Thanks to [Automating Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730906/automating-chrome), [Automating Firefox and Chrome browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320516/automating-firefox-and-chrome-browsers), and lee.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how helpful this may be but...

You could investigate [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/), I am not sure as to how well Chrome is supported, according to the docs it is at least partially supported. You could perhaps use FireFox for full support...

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking at Selenium and Watir/Watin, found them in answers around stackoverflow.  
I need to work on the chrome remote desktop, so firefox is not an option (unless it's got a remote desktop too :D).

Comment: Found this, not free though... http://remotedesktopmanager.com/Home/ExternalAddOns

Comment: I guess i'll do without it, my needs are not so pressing. Still, it's useful to know that there is one.